# Все метки на экране

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Вывожу на карту массив меток: `map.geoObjects.add()`. Есть в `Api` возможность центрировать и отдалить камеру так, чтобы все метки были видны на экране? Соответственно, если на карте только 1 метка, то масштаб увеличен; если несколько - камера отдалена так, чтобы все метки попадали на экран.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
storage = ymaps.geoQuery(map.geoObjects);
map.setBounds(storage.getBounds(), {zoomMargin: [30, 30, 30, 30]}); // zoomMargin — отступы точек от краев карты
map.setZoom(map.getZoom()); // хак, который не дает быть зуму больше чем есть в этой точке земного шара
```